# Use of uninitialized value in print function

Tags: perl

I am running the following simple Perl program.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %a = (b => "B", c => "C");

print "Enter b or c: ";

my $input = <STDIN>;

print "The letter you just entered is: ", $input, "\n";

my $d = $a{$input};

print ($d);
```

When I entered b I got the following output with a warning. Line 47 is the last statement print ($d);

```
Enter b or c: b
The letter you just entered is: b

Use of uninitialized value $d in print at C:/Users/lzhang/workspace/Perl5byexample/exer5_3.pl line 47, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Why do I get this warning and how do I fix it?

Comment: strange idea to close this question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `$input` contains new line character besides `b` or `c`. Modify it to trim this charcter:

```
my $input = <STDIN>;        # 1. $input is now "b\n" or "c\n"                             
chomp $input;               # 2. Get rid of new line character
                            #    $input is now "b" or "c"

print "the letter you just entered is: ", $input, "\n";
```

Comment: This IS the root cause! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you hit enter, it adds a newline.  Try adding [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) to get rid of this.

```
chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);
```

You get that warning because the value `b\n` does not map to a value in your hash, thus `$d` is uninitialized.

Comment: thanks! if only I had more reputations to vote up your answer~~

Comment: @Lyn As long as you understand what went wrong, then all is well.  Cheers.